# friendly url without any parameters with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to short my url, mainly to SEO, so I decided to change my url's on my website.

Now the urls looking like

> http://www.domain.com/cat.php?id=5 while the category's name is "example cat"

I want that the url will look like

> http://www.domain.com/example-cat/

How can I do it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to include both the ID *and* the name. Otherwise name changes will break all links stored by search engines, users, etc.

http://www.example.com/5/example-cat/ or http://www.example.com/5-example-cat/ or whatever you like (with the ID still being easily extractable with a regex).

Comment: Are you sure? so how wordpress works? for example - http://wordpress.org/news/2011/01/wordcamp-sf-2011/ without any id's

Comment: Looking at the fact that it is not the same as the title it probably has a field "permalink name" which can (or at leash should) not be changed after setting it.

Comment: You mean the field 'permalink name' is written to htaccess and each post has a row in the htaccess file?

Comment: No. the htaccess just redirects to a php script

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't. You'd set it up to rewrite from:

```
http://www.domain.com/5/
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/cat.php?id=5
```

If you wanted to use the category names, you'd need to change the php on the back end to accept them.

Answer (score 1):

You could always push 'everything' through your index.php file and use it to bootstrap the entire site..
[have a look at this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/succeed/)

Answer (score 0):

Use htaccess with a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$  /cat.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

So..`example.com/category` would be re-written to `example.com/browse.php?cat=category`.